# Electron: Button with multiple funcitons?

Tags: javascript, function, button, electron

I've created a button that will move a `browserWindow`  to a certain position on the screen; however, I could only get it to work when I used 2 separate buttons, one to move the window and one to put it back in place. I've been trying to make them into one button, which will open and close the window.

Here is my current code for the 2 individual buttons :

Main.js

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');

  ipcMain.on('expClose', function(e,width, height) {
    globalThis.open;
    open = true;
   console.log(open); 
    if (open = true) {
      mainWindow.setPosition(width - 75, height - 450);
      console.log("chnages")
      open = false;
    };

    
  });
  
  ipcMain.on('expOpen', function(e,width, height) {
   console.log("Recieved 1")
   mainWindow.setPosition(width, height);
   open = true;
      
  });
```

Render.js

```
let close = document.getElementById('expClose');
close.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  console.log("renderer");
 ipcRenderer.send('expClose',width, height);


});

let open = document.getElementById('expOpen');
open.addEventListener('click', function(event){
 ipcRenderer.send('expOpen',width - 500, height - 450);


});
```

My previous attempts at combining this into one button were to have a variable called open, which will be set at 0(or true) for open then 1( or false) for closed, and each time the button is clicked, it will alternate between that value and change the current window position depending on the set value, however, I couldn't get this to work.

How can I combine these two buttons into one?

PS: The console log was just there to ensure the code was being communicated successfully between files.

Comment: @Ali Shams Thank you for the edit i missed those things in my re read

Comment: You're welcome my friend

Comment: If anyone has the same question as me in the future try using a checkbox type button am currently trying to make this work on my project.